# Do ready solutions for Web API demonstrations (functional testing) exist?

Tags: .net, testing, asp.net-web-api

We need to show the demo of our service.

It would be nice to have functionality allowing to script [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) or [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm)

The example of scenario:
1) Create resource POST
2) Using the returned object, change some of its parameteres, issue PUT request.
3) ... and so on

It's easy to implement this either as simple console app or as JS web page. But this requires time and we also need some presentation capabilities: show formatted response, http status and other stuff like that. May be software for that purpose already exists...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [Advanced REST Client for the Chrome Browser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) fits your needs.